# Add a dynamic on click event to a button in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-apps-script

I want to create an interactive web application using html service google apps script.

I am having trouble with adding an `onclick` event with a function into a button.

The functions are executed when the web loads for the first time, but not when it is clicked. If I click the button later, nothing happens.

[Here is the link for my project](https://script.google.com/d/1t3_AoKpRMJmPpedQ-7yCvW35frRbNYBZU7mTverS8OYmLH9mwZsdVY8d/edit?usp=drive_web)

Code.gs :

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
function getmenus() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B5vEst6Tvg8nfmhRU1h4V044ODJlX2VxeHdKeFFicUx0UlMzMWhZcUxjTkRHSlZiR3FlT1k');
  var datax = []
  var result = [[]];
  var filess = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (filess.hasNext()) {
    datax.push(filess.next());
  }
  datax.sort(function sorting(x,y){
      var xp = x.getName().toLowerCase();
      var yp = y.getName().toLowerCase();
      return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;
    });
  for (var a in datax) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(datax[a].getId());
    var info = ss.getSheetByName('Info');
    var url = info.getRange('B1').getValue();
    result[a] = [datax[a].getName(),datax[a].getId(),url];
  }
  return result;
}
function processmenu(result) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(result);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  return values;
}
```

JavaScript.html :

```
<script>

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadmenu).getmenus();

function loadmenu(result) {
  var mainmenu = document.getElementById('menunav');
  mainmenu.innerHTML='';
  for (var a in result) {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    var hidden = document.createElement('input');
    hidden.type='hidden';
    hidden.name='name';
    hidden.value=result[a][1];

    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.type='button';
    button.name='menu';
    button.value=result[a][0];
    button.onclick=menuclick(result[a][1]);

    form.appendChild(hidden);
    form.appendChild(button);

    mainmenu.appendChild(form);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    mainmenu.appendChild(br);

  }
}
function menuclick(result) {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateoptions).processmenu(result);
}
function updateoptions(values) {
  alert(values);
}

</script>
```

Please help me to solve the problem and maybe how to rewrite the code in a better way.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the trigger to you your function? You will need to link the event to a trigger, in order for the event to execute a method.

Comment: Do you know how to add "onclick" trigger on this function ? I think it is already done in this line :

button.onclick=menuclick(result[a][1]);

Comment: I updated your Apps Script code.  Thank you for providing access to the file.  That made finding the problem achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one.  Setting the `onclick` attribute using the DOM expects a function.  And you can't use a text formula as the function, because it evaluates to a string instead of an object.  So you need to create a new function with the `new` key word.  Right now you have:

```
button.onclick=menuclick(result[a][1]);
```

Change to:

```
var newFunction = new Function("menuclick('" + result[a][1] + "')");
button.onclick=newFunction;
```

The value of the `onclick` attribute must be a function.  In your case, you need to construct a function with a dynamic argument to be passed.  You can construct the textual part of the formula with a string formula.  But then the string needs to be used to create a function object.

In JavaScript you can concatenate string values with a plus sign.

`"menuclick('"` is a string.

`result[a][1]` is a string.

`"')"` is a string.

Note that you need to isolate the `result[a][1]` part between the two other strings.  This is because `result[a][1]` needs to be evaluated, and a value retrieved from the object array.

I would also put the `google.script.run` call into a window.onload event:

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("window.onload ran!");
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadmenu).getmenus();
};
```

And also, use `IFRAME` sandbox mode:

```
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

Comment: Great thanks @Sandy for your changes to my code. Now I can see the problem that we need to define the function first. I am so sorry I don't have enough reputation point to mark this answer. Thx again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI for anyone else coming here from google, the selected answer above did not work for me.

```
var newFunction = new Function("functionName(" + param + ")");
element.onclick=newFunction;
```

I had to do this instead

```
element.setAttribute("onclick","functionName(" + param + ")");
```